# Aws eks bitbucket pipeline permission error

Tags: bitbucket, amazon-eks

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  tags:
    ecr-release-*:
      - step:
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - apt update -y
            - apt install python3-pip -y
            - pip3 --version
            - pip3 install awscli
            - aws configure set aws_access_key_id "AKIA6J47DSdaUIAZH46DKDDID6UH"
            - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "2dWgDxx5i7Jre0aZJ+tQ3oDve5biYk0ZMDKKASA7554QoJSJSJS"
            - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
            - chmod +x ./kubectl
            - mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
            - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name build_web --region us-west-2
            - kubectl apply -f eks/aws-auth.yaml
            - kubectl apply -f eks/deployment.yaml
            - kubectl apply -f eks/service.yaml

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
```

Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`.
When i am running bitbucket pipeline i am getting below error in screenshot.
I think i already added aws access credentials

Please take a look

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create service account and give permissions, also you need certificate to connect Kubernetes API server.

Here is nice explanation with all details which might be helpful for you: https://medium.com/codeops/continuous-deployment-with-bitbucket-pipelines-ecr-and-aws-eks-791a30b7c84b

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved changing the kube config file. You need to specify the profile you need to use. By default the update-kubeconfig creates the authentication credentials, and put inside the file something like this:

```
- name: arn:aws:eks:{region}:{}account-id:cluster/{cluster-name}
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - {region}
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - {cluster-name}
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: {profile}
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

For son reason aws cli is not picking up the AWS_PROFILE env variable value, so in this case I solved manualy updating the kube config and specifying the --profile in the aws command part:

```
- name: arn:aws:eks:{region}:{}account-id:cluster/{cluster-name}
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
        args:
          - --region
          - {region}
          - eks
          - get-token
          - --profile
          - {profile}
          - --cluster-name
          - {cluster-name}
          command: aws
          #env:
          #- name: AWS_PROFILE
          #  value: {profile}
          interactiveMode: IfAvailable
          provideClusterInfo: false
```